# VBA FileDialog FilePicker locks selected file and folder until Access/Excel is closed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

After a user selects a file using the Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker), the file and directory become locked until Access is closed. Neither the file nor the folder can be moved or deleted. This is confirmed by Microsoft.
According to Microsoft's FileDialog support page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.FileDialog

"Note that when a file is selected using the File open Dialog, the directory containing the selected file will become the current directory for the process. This means that the directory will be locked until the current diectory is changed, or the process terminates. This will prevent the directory from being deleted, moved, or renamed."

This can be confirmed using Win 10's Resource Monitor->CPU->Associated Handles. Search for the folder containing the file and you'll see that Access's PID is holding the folder.

Executing:

`Set FileDialog = Nothing`

has no effect

Does anybody have an idea how to change the current directory or release the file/directory without exiting Access?

Comment: Did you try `ChDir <another path>`?

Comment: Try `ChDir`. Not sure if it will work, but it won't hurt to try. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chdir-statement

Comment: It worked for me but who knows if it works for the OP.

Comment: @Storax Saw your comment after posting mine :)

Comment: And one can also see how the folder name changes in the Resource Monitor.

Comment: Perfect... 
after Set dlgFilePick = Nothing
I added:
chdir currentproject.Path
verified that the file/folder were released
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Storax propose your response as Answer and I'll mark it as such.